# When saving a WAV file in Kotlin (Android) 12 bytes more are added to the file

Tags: android, kotlin, audio, wav

I have a device that records 30 seconds of audio and sends it via BLE to a mobile application. The application must save it and then load it. The raw data is contained in a byte array, so I have to craft the WAV header before saving it. I craft the header according to the official documentation: **https://docs.fileformat.com/audio/wav/**

The code is this:

```
val out = resolver.openOutputStream(uri!!)

val samplerate = 4000
val channels = 1 // audio mono
val RECORDER_BPP =  8 // Bit per sample
val totalDataLen = data.size / 8
Log.d("LEN", ""+totalDataLen)
val byteRate: Int = RECORDER_BPP * samplerate * channels / 8 //   RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLERATE * channels/8;

val header = ByteArray(44)

header[0] = 'R'.code.toByte() // RIFF/WAVE header
header[1] = 'I'.code.toByte()
header[2] = 'F'.code.toByte()
header[3] = 'F'.code.toByte()

header[4] = ((36 + totalDataLen * UByte.SIZE_BITS and 0xff).toByte())
header[5] = ((36 + totalDataLen * UByte.SIZE_BITS shr 8 and 0xff).toByte())
header[6] = ((36 + totalDataLen * UByte.SIZE_BITS shr 16 and 0xff).toByte())
header[7] = ((36 + totalDataLen * UByte.SIZE_BITS shr 24 and 0xff).toByte())

header[8] = 'W'.code.toByte()
header[9] = 'A'.code.toByte()
header[10] = 'V'.code.toByte()
header[11] = 'E'.code.toByte()

header[12] = 'f'.code.toByte() // 'fmt ' chunk
header[13] = 'm'.code.toByte()
header[14] = 't'.code.toByte()
header[15] = ' '.code.toByte()

header[16] = 16 // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
header[17] = 0
header[18] = 0
header[19] = 0

header[20] = 1 // format = 1
header[21] = 0

header[22] = channels.toByte() // channel
header[23] = 0

header[24] = ((samplerate and 0xff).toByte())
header[25] = ((samplerate shr 8 and 0xff).toByte())
header[26] = ((samplerate shr 16 and 0xff).toByte())
header[27] = ((samplerate shr 24 and 0xff).toByte())

header[28] = ((byteRate * UByte.SIZE_BITS and 0xff).toByte()) // 28-31  176400  (Sample Rate * BitsPerSample * Channels) / 8.
header[29] = ((byteRate * UByte.SIZE_BITS shr 8 and 0xff).toByte())
header[30] = ((byteRate * UByte.SIZE_BITS shr 16 and 0xff).toByte())
header[31] = ((byteRate * UByte.SIZE_BITS shr 24 and 0xff).toByte())

//header[32] = (byte) (1); // block align
header[32] = (channels * RECORDER_BPP shr 3).toByte()
// header[33] = 0;
header[33] = (channels * RECORDER_BPP shr 11).toByte()

header[34] = RECORDER_BPP.toByte() // bits per sample
header[35] = 0

header[36] = 'd'.code.toByte()
header[37] = 'a'.code.toByte()
header[38] = 't'.code.toByte()
header[39] = 'a'.code.toByte()
header[40] = ((totalDataLen * UByte.SIZE_BITS and 0xff).toByte())
header[41] = ((totalDataLen * UByte.SIZE_BITS shr 8 and 0xff).toByte())
header[42] = ((totalDataLen * UByte.SIZE_BITS shr 16 and 0xff).toByte())
header[43] = ((totalDataLen * UByte.SIZE_BITS shr 24 and 0xff).toByte())

out?.write(header, 0, 44)


out?.write(data)
out?.close()
```

Now, I use this library to read the file: http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html
and one of the first checks that it does, is that the chunk size (header bytes 4 to 7 included) plus 8, as defined in the official doc for WAV files, is equal to the file size. Opening every other WAV file this is true, but apparently there's something wrong with how I craft the header, because the size of my file ends up being 12 bytes more than chuncksize + 8.

Any help?

Comment: What i miss is the size or length of your data byte array. The file size should be data.length + 44. Or not? Please give the needed info

Comment: `(36 + totalDataLen` For four bytes you add 39. Why? And what is this 39? The four bytes would indicate a length. What kind of length? And how can it be a length is you add 39 to every of the four bytes?

Comment: Quote from the specs: `5 - 8 File size (integer) Size of the overall file - 8 bytes, in bytes (32-bit integer). Typically, you’d fill this in after creation.` That should be `4 bytes` of course. And there is no `36`. And certainly not four times.